# Explain the following combination question in deep details

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $32$ objects are placed along a circle at equal distances. In how many ways can $3$ objects be chosen from among them so that no two of the three chosen objects are adjacent nor diametrically opposite $?$

Comment: @Justpassingby I cant even start with it!

Comment: Start by fixing the order of the choice of the three objects. This means that your result will have to be divided by 6 in the end but it makes the reasoning easier. How many choices are there for the first onject? Then, how many choices are left for the second? And then for the third, taking into account a few different cases depending on the choice of the second?

Comment: such type of question has already been asked i suppose

Comment: @Archis Welankar plz provide link

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions of Justpassingby? How far have you gotten?

Comment: For those who put my question on hold tell me whats wrong in the question.I can't understand this!!!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are $32$ ways to place the first object. After that there are $28$ places for the second object. That is, there are $32\cdot28=896$ ways to place the first two objects.

If the first two objects are $2$ places apart, then there are $25$ places for the third; if the first two places are $15$ apart, there are $26$ places for the third; otherwise, there are $24$ places.

[image]

Of the $896$ ways to place the first two, $64$ have them being two apart and $64$ have them being $15$ apart. Thus, there are
$$
\overbrace{\ 64\cdot26\ }^{\text{first two $15$ apart}}+\overbrace{\ 64\cdot25\ }^{\text{first two $2$ apart}}+\overbrace{768\cdot24}^{\text{otherwise}}=21696
$$
ways to pick three objects where we care about their order. For each of the ways to arrange without caring about order, there are $3!=6$ ways to reorder the objects; therefore, if we don't care about the order, there are
$$
\frac16\cdot21696=3616
$$
ways to arrange three objects.

Comment: By  counting the first two placements as $32\cdot28$ each *pattern* has been double counted, e.g. $1-3-y$ and $3-1-y$, where $y$ will be placed for the case when first two are two apart. So $21696$ from your answer divided by $(2\cdot32)$ gives my answer of 339 as patterns have been considered identical under rotation. I don't see why there should be division by $3!$. Btw, your diagrams were very aesthetically pleasing ! And after all this, the question is on hold....

Comment: @trueblueanil: The question is not about patterns that are similar under rotation; the question is about objects set around a circle. The question asks how many triples can be chosen where there are no adjacent or opposite neighbors.

Comment: In that case the answer should be 10,848

Comment: I am pretty sure this is correct. We have counted the number of ways to choose an object to be colored red (the first chosen), an object to be painted green (the second chosen), and an object to be painted blue (the third chosen). For each choice of three objects, there are $3!$ ways to paint them red, green, and blue. Thus, we need to divide the number of choices we originally computed by $6$.

Comment: I have run this through Mathematica and it confirms my answer:

Comment: `good[a_, b_, c_] := 
 Block[{d = Abs[a - b], e = Abs[b - c], f = Abs[c - a]}, 
  d != 0 && d != 1 && d != 16 && d != 31 && e != 0 && e != 1 && 
   e != 16 && e != 31 && f != 0 && f != 1 && f != 16 && f != 31]`

Comment: `Block[{s = 0}, 
 For[i = 1, i <= 30, ++i, 
  For[j = i + 1, j <= 31, ++j, 
   For[k = j + 1, k <= 32, ++k, s += If[good[i, j, k], 1, 0]]]]; s]`

Comment: With 8 objects, following your method, for the first two: 8*4 = 32. 16 of them will be three apart, with 2 places for the third, and 16 will be two apart with only 1 place for the third. No "others". 16*2+16*1 = 48, 48/6 = 8. Which are these 8 ? I get just three *patterns* [1-3-6,1-4-7,1-6-7] and 3*8 = 24 triples.

Comment: If you program the logic you used, you will obviously get the same answer. I have enumerated for 8 objects. I also enumerated for 16 objects and got 51 patterns, 51*16 triples.

Comment: I have generated all triples from $32$ objects and counted only those that satisfy the given conditions.

Comment: Pl. see my first comment. 32*28 double counts for the first two, explained in more detail there. If that is adjusted, our answers agree. I have also listed for a small example. If my observations are incorrect, what is the flaw in my approach ? The ultimate truth is that both answers can't be correct.

Comment: With $8$ objects there are $8$ triples. $\{\{1,3,6\}, \{1,4,6\}, \{1,4,7\}, \{2,4,7\}, \{2,5,7\}, \{2,5,8\}, \{3,5,8\}, \{3,6,8\}\}$

Comment: For even $n\ge6$, my method gives $\frac{n((n-6)^2+2)}6$.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I counted 3 *patterns*, multiplied by 8 (if desired) for rotation = 24 You counted all permutations of triples to get 48, divided by 6 to get  triples. Happy new year (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I am considering objects to be identical, and  arrangements to be identical under rotation.

Number the objects $1-32$ clockwise, and let the first object chosen be $1$  We can't now choose $32, 2$ and $17$ (the two adjacent, and the one opposite).

Let us choose the second object in the right semi-circle from the $14$ positions available, and the third from the left semi-circle from which 
we can now only  choose from $(14-1)$ positions, *except that number $16$ can be combined with $14$ from the other semicircle, since number $32$ was already barred when we started with $1$*, thus yielding $ 14\cdot13 +1$ patterns.

But we could also choose the second and third object from the *same* semicircle, From $14$ such in one semicircle, there are $\binom{14}{2}$ combos of two from which $13$ adjacent ($3-4$ through $15-16$) need to be subtracted, yielding $78$ patterns for each semicircle.

Finally, we get $(14\cdot13) + 1 +  (2\cdot78) = 339$

**NOTE**

The formula this yields for $2n$ points, $n\ge4$ is:
$(n-2)(n-3) + 1 + 2\left[\binom{n-2}{2} - (n-3)\right]$

This yields $51$ patterns for $16$ points, which can easily be verified by enumeration

[You could start with $8$ points, which has only $3$ patterns, $1-3-6, 1-4-6$ and $1-4-7$ . Note that I am always fixing one point as $1$ ]

Comment: Note that the difference in the 2 answers is because robjohn has counted triples, I have counted patterns.